# Stepwise Regression with ROC

Tags: r, regression, auc

I am learning data science with R on DataCamp. In one exercise, I have to build a stepwise regression model. Even though I create the stepwise model successfully, roc() function doesn't accept the response and it gives an error like: "'response' has more than two levels. Consider setting 'levels' explicitly or using 'multiclass.roc' instead"

I want to learn how to handle this problem so I wrote my code below.

```
# Specify a null model with no predictors
null_model <- glm(donated ~ 1, data = donors, family = "binomial")

# Specify the full model using all of the potential predictors
full_model <- glm(donated ~ ., data = donors, family = "binomial")

# Use a forward stepwise algorithm to build a parsimonious model
step_model <- step(null_model, scope = list(lower = null_model, upper = full_model), direction = "forward")

# Estimate the stepwise donation probability
step_prob <- predict(step_model, type = "response")
# Plot the ROC of the stepwise model
library(pROC)
ROC <- roc( step_prob, donors$donated)
plot(ROC, col = "red")
auc(ROC)
```

Comment: try this: `roc(step_prob, factor(donors$donated))`, also on a side note, you can also check for `library('caTools')` .  it means that you have more than two categories, if that is not expected, then you have to check for your data. Factors are weird in a sense that even if you delete their values from a data sets their old reference is present, wrapping with `factor` command resets them. All the very best. Also it would be great if you can `dput` and/or `str(dataframe)` to let people understand what your data contains else it will always be a guess work. Thanks

Comment: please provide data

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order of roc function's argument and the error was solved.

```
library(pROC)
ROC <- roc( donors$donated, step_prob)
plot(ROC, col = "red")
auc(ROC)
```